# Printing attributes from another class

Tags: python, class

Say I have this piece of code:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Other:
    def __init__(self):
        str = input("Type a, b, c, or d: ")
        print(str.name)

a = Foo('apple')
b = Foo('bear')
c = Foo('chicken')
d = Foo('duck')
```

Obviously, this program won't work as `str` is a string and not an instance.
Is there any way to print the attribute `name` from the instances of the `Foo` class out using code in the `Other` class?
Or using code in the `Foo` class is the only way?

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? As it stands, there is no point `Other` being a class at all.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to access global variables using name. You can use [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) to get a dictionary that map global variable names to objects:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Other:
    def __init__(self):
        v = input("Type a, b, c, or d: ")
        print(globals()[v].name)

a = Foo('apple')
b = Foo('bear')
c = Foo('chicken')
d = Foo('duck')

Other()
```

**UPDATE**

Using `globals` is a sign of bad design.

You'd better to use a sequence or mapping to store multiple objects.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Other:
    def __init__(self, mapping):
        v = input("Type a, b, c, or d: ")
        print(mapping[v].name)

foo_list = [Foo('apple'), Foo('bear'), Foo('chicken'), Foo('duck')]
mapping = {foo.name[0]: foo for foo in foo_list}  # dict comprehension
Other(mapping)
```

Comment: The alternative does not seem very practical when dealing with larger groups of objects.

Comment: @user3774359, If that's the problem, you should use list, instead of individual variable: `foo_list = [Foo('apple'), Foo('bear'), Foo('chicken'), Foo('duck')]
mapping = {foo.name[0]: foo for foo in foo_list}`

Answer (score 0):

The actual way to fix this is to use `Other` class to create your `Foo` objects, and then keep these `Foo` objects as an attribute of the `Other` class.

Fiddling with `globals()` may do what you want, but it is not solving the bigger problem with the design:

```
class Foo:
   def __init__(self, name):
      self.name = name

class Other:
   def __init__(self):
      self.foos = {'a': Foo('apple'), 'b': Foo('bear'),
                   'c': Foo('chicken'), 'd': Foo('duck')}

   def ask(self):
      i = input('Please enter a,b,c or d: ')
      obj = self.foos.get(i)
      if obj:
         print('You selected {0.name}'.format(obj))
      else:
         print('Sorry, {} is not a valid choice'.format(i))

z = Other()
z.ask()
```